# Setting border to a recylerview element reproduces on scrolling back to the same object

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapterview

I have a recycler view of image views and upon longpress I try to give the image view a border. When I scrolldown and come back to the same object the boder is found on someother image.(It is ok coz... the recycler view deletes itself and creates back and so the position changes).

So what I did is I stored the image URl on long press and after scrolling back I drew the Border on the image based on the image URL.

Now the problem is the border that came previously(wrong position) is also drawn....how to get rid of it.

In simple terms. How to make the recyclerview forget the data changes?
(Notifydatasetchanged....Something like that)....

thankz in advance....

Answer (score 1):

This is the problem caused by the position at which the boarder was made is not the same position after the scroll on `RecyclerView` you can easily fix this by allowing your object to remember if it was selected by long-press or not

Assume this is the class you have

```
class Item {
  // here you already have your instance variables 
  // add another one
  boolean isSelected;
}
```

when you long-press on an item make this instance variable of respective `Item`, `true` and provide it a boarder.

when you populate your List in `RecyclerView's` adapter what you can check is if the `isSelected` is true than make respective `imageView` have a boarder. otherwise don't

by doing so you will be independent of the position of the item with respective of the scroll. So your Item will retain the boarder which was actually selected.

Comment: @JENISON you are welcome, let me know how it goes for you